# How do I not print a command in the terminal using node-pty and xterm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, pty, xtermjs

I'm using xterm.js, node-pty, and electron to build a node repl like terminal (similar to repl.it). I'm using this piece of code to run the file and output it to the terminal:

`ptyProcess.write("vm.runInNewContext(fs.readFileSync('dir/file.js', 'utf8'))\r")`

But I always get this printed to the terminal:

```
> vm.runInNewContext(fs.readFileSync('dir/file.js', 'utf8'))
5
>
```

I know `ptyProcess.write()` writes to the terminal, but is there a way to run a command without printing it to the terminal? How can I get the terminal to print something like this:

```
>
5
>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

use `ptyProcess.on('data', function(data){})` to filter data

xterm.js docs link: [onevent-callback](https://xtermjs.org/docs/api/terminal/#onevent-callback)

Comment: But how do you execute it in the shell without printing it to the shell?